# How to show image browse button in tinymce4 and upload image by php？

Tags: php, tinymce-4

my tinymce(ver 4.1) "insert/edit image" dialog doesn't have a image browse button, but I want to add the button just look like tinymce official demo shows), can anyone help me?by the way,how can i use PHP to upload image when I click the image button?I need your help~
I am new here,and i am sorry i didn't have enough reputation to post images.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!
I need define a javascript function, called "file_browser_callback",and "file_browser_callback" attribute to the function,for example:

```
function myCustomFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
    // Do custom browser logic
    win.document.forms[0].elements[field_name].value = 'my browser value';
}

tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        file_browser_callback : myCustomFileBrowser
});
```

See also:  http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:file_browser_callback